# to check any procedure or trigger written ove table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to check in Oracle that if is there any Procedure or trigger written on the database table which insert the records in the table.

Please help me to find out this because I have an existing table and want to check that in that table how records would be insert.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for [dependencies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/dependencies.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies between objects are maintained in the system and can be read from DBA_DEPENDENCIES (or ALL_ or USER_DEPENDENCIES).

The only limitation is that dynamic statements (eg using execute immediate) are not included because they are not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code snippet. Hope this helps!

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT owner,
    name,
    type,
    referenced_owner,
    referenced_name,
    referenced_type,
    owner sdev_link_owner,
    name sdev_link_name,
    type sdev_link_type
  FROM ALL_DEPENDENCIES
  WHERE REFERENCED_OWNER = 'OBJECT_OWNER'
  AND referenced_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
  ) sub1
ORDER BY 3 ASC;
```